# Why $T=X_1X_2$ is not a sufficient statistic?

Tags: self-study, decision-theory

Why $T=X_1X_2$ is not a sufficient statistic?

Suppose I want to show $T=x_1x_2$ is sufficient and with this distribution

$$ x \sim \frac{\theta^xe^{-\theta}}{x!}$$

Chug and plug, you will get $$\frac{\theta^{x_1x_2}e^{-\theta}}{x_1x_2!}$$

Why this doesn't satisfy Factorization Theorem, thus not a sufficient statistic.

To me it's perfectly fine, I got them into 2 parts.
One part is: $\theta^{x_1x_2}e^{-\theta}$.
The other is: $\frac{1}{{x_1x_2!}}$.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I assume when you say $x\sim\frac{\theta^x e^{-\theta}}{x!}$ what you mean is that X is a Poisson random variable with parameter $\theta$. From the context of your question, I'm guessing you are given a vector $\vec{X}=[X_1,X_2]$, where both $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent and identically distributed as the original $X$ random variable. In order to apply the factorization theorem, you will need to first find the **joint PMF** $$P_\vec{X}(\vec{x})=P({X_1=x_1},{X_2=x_2})$$

Hint: If you are having trouble finding this joint PMF, remember from probability theory that the independence assumption provides an easy way to compute it from the individual PMFs. Finally, rearrange the terms in the PMF and apply the factorization theorem to derive a sufficient statistic. The factorization theorem is: $$P_\vec{X}(\vec{x})=g(\theta|T(\vec{x}))h(\vec{x})$$
Where $T(\vec{x})$ is the sufficient statistic.

Comment: but the answer is: this is not a sufficient statistic.  Also, joint PMF gives $T=x_1+x_2$, and I see why that is true.